# remote login identityserver3

Tags: c#, security, single-sign-on, identityserver3

I'm currently trying to connect my existing behaviour into IdentityServer3.
What I want to happen is when I post my login form back with username and password I can call my IdentityServer and authenticate in a single post request.
Are there existing helpers to support this?
Sorry If this has been asked I've been trawling around all day and haven't found anything.

Answer (score 0):

So I have figured this out after loads of reading and playing, basically what I wanted was the resourceOwner flow which would allow me to authenticate without the browser. This isn't recommended as you loose the sso benefits. The other approach I looked at was to pass the post form values, username and password to the preauthenticate method on identity server. This seemed extremely hacky to me. I'll probably just use the normal flow if the client will allow it.